# RuntimeException: Runtime Error Could not run dbt

Tags: runtime-error, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I used `dbt init` to create a profiles.yml in my `.dbt` folder. It looks like this:

```
spring_project:
  outputs:
    dev:
      account: xxx.snowflakecomputing.com
      database: PROD_DWH
      password: password
      role: SYSADMIN
      schema: STG
      threads: 1
      type: snowflake
      user: MYUSERNAME
      warehouse: DEV_XS_WH
  target: dev
```

Now, I created a new folder on my desktop which only contains a `dbt_project.yml` file that has this:

```
profile: 'spring_project'
```

When I run this from my project folder:

```
dbt debug --config-dir
```

I get this:

```
21:48:59  Running with dbt=1.2.1
21:48:59  To view your profiles.yml file, run:

open /Users/myusername/.dbt
```

However, when I run dbt

```
dbt run --profiles-dir /Users/myusername/.dbt
```

I get this:

```
21:43:39  Encountered an error while reading the project:
21:43:39    ERROR: Runtime Error
  Invalid config version: 1, expected 2

Error encountered in /Users/myusername/Desktop/spring_project/dbt_project.yml
21:43:39  Encountered an error:
Runtime Error
  Could not run dbt
21:43:39  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/task/base.py", line 108, in from_args
    config = cls.ConfigType.from_args(args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/config/runtime.py", line 226, in from_args
    project, profile = cls.collect_parts(args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/config/runtime.py", line 194, in collect_parts
    partial = Project.partial_load(project_root, verify_version=version_check)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/config/project.py", line 639, in partial_load
    return PartialProject.from_project_root(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/config/project.py", line 485, in from_project_root
    raise DbtProjectError(
dbt.exceptions.DbtProjectError: Runtime Error
  Invalid config version: 1, expected 2

Error encountered in /Users/myusername/Desktop/spring_project/dbt_project.yml

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/main.py", line 129, in main
    results, succeeded = handle_and_check(args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/main.py", line 191, in handle_and_check
    task, res = run_from_args(parsed)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/main.py", line 218, in run_from_args
    task = parsed.cls.from_args(args=parsed)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/task/base.py", line 185, in from_args
    return super().from_args(args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/task/base.py", line 114, in from_args
    raise dbt.exceptions.RuntimeException("Could not run dbt") from exc
dbt.exceptions.RuntimeException: Runtime Error
  Could not run dbt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the reason is lack of `config-version`:

> dbt.exceptions.DbtProjectError: Runtime Error
> Invalid config version: 1, expected 2

[config-version](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/project-configs/config-version)

> ```
> config-version: 2
> ```
>
> Specify your dbt_project.yml as using the v2 structure.
>
> Default:
>
> **Without this configuration, dbt will assume your dbt_project.yml uses the version 1 syntax, which was deprecated in dbt v0.19.0.**

Comment: I changed my .yml file to this: ```config-version: 2
profile: 'spring_project'``` and ran the same dbt command as above but still got the same error

Comment: Just realized that the error message is slightly different now. It says: ```Required "name" field not present in project```